# Does a "round"'ed value guarantee equality?

Tags: python, floating-point

Suppose i have some floating point value `x`. Suppose we do `x = round(x, 3)`, i.e., we truncate after the 3rd decimal place.

Then we if we check something like:

```
x == 0.222
```

Does this guarantee there's no comparison after the 3rd decimal place?

Comment: From what I can tell it may be worth checking out [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Comment: I suggest checking https://stackoverflow.com/q/5595425/4046632

Comment: @Jab I realized I should have asked another question first. I just asked it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304463/round-and-floating-point-precision I feel like the premise I have here is actaully wrong

Comment: As a shortcut, you can use `repr(round(x,3))==repr(round(y,3))`. While the internal representation of flaot might be different even after rounding, its representation after rounding will be the same. As a longcut (and the right way) you can either wade into the bits or use `Decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean. Consider the following examples:

```
>>> x = round(0.2221,3)
>>> x == 0.222
True
>>> x = round(0.2225,3)
>>> x == 0.222
False
>>> x = round(0.2221,3)
>>> y = 0.2221
>>> x == y
False
>>>
```

In the first case, `x` rounds down to `0.222`, so the two are equal. In the second case, it is rounded up, so they are not. In the third case, even after being rounded down, it is still not equal to a value with more digits after the decimal point, which would still round down.

If you want to guarantee only the first three numbers after the decimal are used, you need to truncate (or round) each number.

Does this help?

Comment: Upvoted, but I realized my premise may be actually wrong. Here's the actual use case that we have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77304463/round-and-floating-point-precision#77304463 (It's a separate question that I should have asked instead of this one)

Comment: @roulette01 - You might want to try multiplying by 1000 and converting to an integer before storing in a db, and then eiher think of yourself as working in units of milli-whatevers, or remembering to dive by 1000 when you need to.