# Round and floating point precision

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, floating-point, rounding

We're writing data to a sql database (sqlite3 to be specific). For a particular column, `quantity`, it is specified as a `REAL` (float)  column because we store the `quantity` as multiples of 1000 (so the integer quantity is divided by `1000`). So the stored quantity is accurate to the 3rd decimal place, but because of floating point precision, we sometimes see random non-zero values after the 3rd decimal place.

My colleague is trying to use `round` to handle this, but I don't see how this will help with the issue. In fact, I don't think it does anything for this particular problem.

My understanding is there is no way to actually resolve this issue when writing if we insist of using floats.

Comment: I wouldn't use float. Knowing nothing about SQLite, but is there a decimal data type?

Comment: what is the reason to save data as multiples of 1000 if you [want to] save with precision up to 3rd decimal? It doesn't make sense. I.e. what do you gain if store 1.234 instead of 1234?

Comment: @buran i honestly have no idea. I've been asking the same question to the original authors of the code. i want to change it to an integer. but for the purpose of this post, is there an answer to my question?

Comment: SQLite has no true decimal type, but you could just round the output. Assuming your number is less than 15 digits long, `round(x, 3)` is guaranteed to recover the original number put into the database, as the 64 bit floating point representation of your number is guaranteed to differ by no more than 1 part in 1.11e+16. If you have a number larger than that, you'll silently lose precision.

Comment: Although SQLite does not have a true decimal type, it does have DECIMAL, which is internally implemented as a floating point number, but handles all of the rounding for you. More information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757722/how-to-use-sqlite-decimal-precision-notation

Comment: @NickODell you mean round the output of the sql query?

Comment: @roulette01 Right. Though, now that I think about it, it would probably be better to convert the output to Python's [fixed point decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) before rounding, as floating point can't store a number like 0.001 exactly. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583273/how-to-round-a-python-decimal-to-2-decimal-places). That would be important if you intended to do math on these values.

Comment: @NickODell sure, but this handles the python side. we still need to handle it properly within sql right? i was looking at fixed point represntation in sqlite and it doesn't seem it has one, so if we use `REAL` in sqlite, and fixed point in python, it still gets converted from fixed pt to REAL (float) when writing to sql, so the problem still perissts

Comment: @roulette01 Yes, that's what I mean about DECIMAL not being a true decimal type. Other databases, such as Postgres or MySQL, have decimal types. If you're sticking with SQLite, you could use REAL, you can use TEXT, and that's pretty much it for options.

Comment: @roulette01 "we sometimes see random non-zero values after the 3rd decimal place." --> Rather than only _describe_ the values, post the inputs and values.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CAST(quantity * 1000 AS INT)..... will truncate any random non-zero values after the 3rd decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a [FP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)
question than a SQL / python question.

Consider these well-known results:

```
Python 3.11.5 ...
>>>
>>> .1 + .2
0.30000000000000004
>>> 
>>> .3 - .1
0.19999999999999998
>>> 
>>>
>>>
>>> 1 / 3
0.3333333333333333
```

Many folks use base ten (`2 × 5`), and three has
no common factors with two and five,
so in decimal notation we must resort
to an infinite repeating decimal.
Is `.33` the right answer? Kind of.
Is `.333`? Closer. But your pen runs
out of ink before you can write it all down.
In this case what we wrote down is always
a tiny ϵ less than the desired value.

Similarly, expressing `.1` or `.2` as a
binary fraction will inevitably lead to
an infinite repeating <del>"decimal"</del> binary fraction,
because five and two are relatively prime.
So when you **write** `.1` you're thinking "one-tenth",
but inside those 53 bits of FP significand it's a repeating fraction.
Crucially, it's a *truncated* fraction, cut off at the 53rd bit.
And we store the one that is *closest* to the desired number of tenths.
Sometimes that is a little over, sometimes a little under what's desired.
We have +/- ϵ error, and it's unavoidable when using FP representation.

---

You don't want to use FP representation,
since clearly the ϵ error is trouble for your business use case.

Fix the representation. Use INTEGER.
Or use sql DECIMAL, which is simply scaled integer
using your specified precision of three decimal places.

When converting from an inappropriate to an appropriate representation,
using ROUND() always makes sense.
If you instead choose to truncate to int,
be sure to  first add a small epsilon.
Otherwise half the time you'll have an off-by-one error.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it sounds pointless to do this before storing in the database, if the database is storing the data as a float. Rounding would be warranted if using fixed-point precision ie decimal data-type in database.

If storing as float, you can use BETWEEN in SQL or [isclose](https://peps.python.org/pep-0485/) in Python.